# How to enable the summary tab showing above in each query in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know it probably is super simple and just need to click a couple of tabs, but I couldn't find there are instructions to enable or disable this feature in SQL Server Management Studio like the picture below.

So for each query, are there any setting it will show the stats (MAX, MIN,AVG, etc.) above the each queries?

[image]

Comment: I've never seen this in SSMS. Are you sure this is a feature in SSMS? Are these stats in reference to the query execution, or are they in reference to a selected column in the results window?

Comment: Thank you for replying. Honestly, I am not sure whether it's a original feature or a plug-in in SSMS, but I am sure it's not in reference to a selected column in the results window. It appears above the results window in each query like automatically.

Comment: This is not a native feature of SSMS. Where does your image come from.

Comment: That is not a standard feature of SSMS. That status bar is a feature of the Standard and Ultimate editions of SQL Refactor Studio, a paid commercial plugin for SSMS.

Comment: @Stu, from one of my colleagues, but he doesn't either.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning Gotcha, that make sense, probably be installed originally.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using dbForge SQL complete (paid subscription) you would just want to disable the "Summary Panel Visibility".

[image]